# Change interlinear space in ggplot title?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I use `\n` with `labs(title="whatever \n comes after this")` I end up with quite a big space between the lines. Is there a way to influence it? (I mean except font-size of the title itself).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can do something like this ( option **lineheight** to modify line spacing)

```
  p <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars)
  p <- p + ggtitle("whatever \n comes after this") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.1))
  p
```

Comment: very pretty. thanks agstudy. Is there to influence align to? Cause everything is centered so far?

Comment: ah, I see that's just the `vjust` option for the element_text. slick.

Answer (score 1):

To perfectly center everything (which `\n` will not do in several cases), keep every piece of text the same size or being able to relatively adjust it if there are more than 2 lines (which is useful in some cases) and at the same time being able to adjust the interlinear space, use this instead:

```
labs(title=expression(atop(textstyle("whateverline1"),atop(textstyle("whateverline2"),atop(scriptscriptstyle(""),textstyle("whateverline3"))))))
```

Then use `labeller=label_parsed`

This also works for `facet_grid`, `xlab` and `ylab`

Note the `atop` and `textstyle` to position the text whilst keeping it all the same size and the `scriptscriptstyle("")` to control spacing between lines. You can also use varied relative sizes of text using `scriptstyle` or `scriptscriptstyle` depending on your needs