# How to change line spacing in ggplot xlab?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

My X axis label is too long, so I used `xlab(expression(atop(paste("Hello world"^"TM ", ":Hi"),paste("hello again"^"TM",": Hi"))))` to split it into two lines. The line spacing is too big, and I applied the method `axis.title.x=element_text(lineheight=0.2)` to change line spacing, but it did not change anything. The method was adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510971/change-interlinear-space-in-ggplot-title). My question is how to change line spacing for xlab. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @just_rookie! Have you found a suitable solution meanwhile? This seems to have been addressed as an issue on ggplot2's GitHub repo as well - [#2043](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2043)

Answer (score 1):

To perfectly center everything (which `\n` will not do), keep every piece of text the same size whatever the number of lines and at the same time being able to adjust the interlinear space, use this instead:

```
xlab(expression(atop(textstyle("whateverline1"),atop(textstyle("whateverline2"),atop(scriptscriptstyle(""),textstyle("whateverline3"))))))
```

Then use `labeller=label_parsed`

This also works for `facet_grid`, `title` and `ylab`

Note the `atop` and `textstyle` to position the text whilst keeping it all the same size and the `scriptscriptstyle("")` to control spacing between lines. You can also use varied relative sizes of text using `scriptstyle` or `scriptscriptstyle` depending on your needs and of course use `axis.title.x=element_text(size=whatevernumber)` in the theme section

Answer (score 1):

## 1 - Solution with two `atop` calls

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53934616/5193830), every time we call `atop()` the text gets smaller, but also the gap between the lines. 
So for your two lines example, we could call `atop()` two times, which forces 3 lines, but we set the first line empty so that the next `atop` plots the text smaller and also the a smaller gap between the lines. Then we tweak a bit the text size and the margins of the title in `theme`:

Here the issue is illustrated - the gap between the two lines should be reduced.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
# Your usual atop call
label_1 <- expression(atop(x = paste("Hello world"^"TM ", ": Hi"),
                           y = paste("hello again"^"TM ", ": Hi")))
p + xlab(label_1)
```

[image]

**Proposed solution with two `atop` calls:**

```r
# Trick with two atop calls
label_2 <- expression(atop(x = "", # Empty first line might do the trick
                           y = atop(x = paste("Hello world"^"TM ", ": Hi"),
                                    y = paste("hello again"^"TM ", ": Hi"))))
# Since the second atop forces smaller text (and also smaller gap between
# lines), then we need to increase the text manually with axis.title.x in
# theme(). Also adjust the top margin of the title since the first line is
# empty but still takes space.
p + xlab(label_2) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15,
                                    margin = margin(t = -2, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0,
                                                    unit = "mm")))
```

[image]

---

## 2 - Solution with `cowplot::draw_label`

Another hack, would be to call `cowplot::draw_label` two times (suggested in [this](https://github.com/stefano-meschiari/latex2exp/issues/11#issuecomment-441577714) discussion). Again, we need to tweak a bit the position and making space for the custom two lines axis title.

I gave more explanations about this approach and also using `ggplot2::annotation_custom()` in [ggplot2 two-line label with expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54183969/5193830).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'cowplot'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     ggsave

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
# Make enough space for custom two lines axis title
p <- p + xlab("") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15,
                                    margin = margin(t = 7, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0,
                                                    unit = "mm")))

line_1 <- expression(paste("Hello world"^"TM ", ": Hi"))
line_2 <- expression(paste("hello again"^"TM ", ": Hi"))
# Or avoid paste()
# line_1 <- expression("Hello world" ^ "TM" ~ ": Hi")
# line_2 <- expression("hello again" ^ "TM" ~ ": Hi")

# Use cowplot::draw_label to plot two lines of text. Need to tweak a bit the
# position until we get it right.
ggdraw(p) + 
  draw_label(line_1, x = 0.55, y = 0.08) +
  draw_label(line_2, x = 0.55, y = 0.027)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>